# content security policy frame-ancestor directive vs x-frame-options http header

Tags: content-security-policy

As per my understanding, X-Frame-Options header have

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

WHen I read about CSP Frame-ancestors, it is also having

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none';

Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://www.example.org;
```

Where do these differ?